# PHP : Find array pattern in string using regex

Tags: php, regex

I have a string like this it is array pattern :

```
["foo","bar","bra bra","xxx123"]
```

How can i get the `foo`,`bar`,`bra bra`,`xxx123`
Pattern is `["","",""]`

Comment: that appears to be valid json so you should be able to use [json_decode](http://www.php.net/json_decode).

Comment: @JonathanKuhn - We know nothing about the contents of the strings outside the ASCII printable range, so `json_decode()` is a risk

Comment: How exactly is json_decode a risk? It converts a string to an object or array. json_decode isn't vulnerable to attacks. There is no code execution like in unserialize. And any characters outside of the "ascii printable range" will just end up as part of the string. Same as if you used a regular expression or explode to get the string contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it without regex:

```
$result = explode('","', trim($str, '[]"'));
```

or with regex:

```
if (preg_match_all('~"([^"]*)"~', $str, $m))
    $result = $m[1];
```

or a regex to handle escaped quotes:

```
if (preg_match_all('~"([^"\\\]*(?s:\\\.[^"\\\]*)*)"~', $str, $m))
    $result = $m[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Since php 5.4 that is a shorthanded way of doing an array.

See: http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Specific quote:

> As of PHP 5.4 you can also use the short array syntax, which replaces
>   array() with [].

Therefore the basic way is like any other array:

```
$arr = ["foo","bar"];

foreach($arr AS $arg){
    echo $arg; //you can add your logic here for comma seperating or beautifying
}
```

Comment: Fairly certain `foreach` won't iterate over a string, which is what the OP is working with...

Comment: Ok OP said array pattern which is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect, that a regex might be the wrong tool - try `explode`!

```
$string='["foo","bar","bra bra","xxx123"]';

//Remove start/end
if (substr($string,0,2)!='["') die('Malformed start!');
if (substr($string,-2)!='"]') die('Malformed end!');
$string=substr($string, 2, -2);
//Now explode
$array=explode('","', $string);

print_r($array);
```